# ContentViews Subview not changing height dynamically in UIScrollView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView holding a ContentView, with that ContentView holding other interchangeable UIViews.
Can get the multiple UIViews to show, however one of the UIViews have dynamic content, so changes its height if you click on a button, can also shrink back.

The structure looks like this - UIScrollView -> ContentView(UIView) -> UIView : [image]

I cannot get the Autolayout anchors correct, the content size doesn't change when the UIView changes height (button click). So I can scroll to see the growth in content, but its not clickable anymore, the extra growth height is the same height as what is not clickable (the ContentView didn't change its height)

**Current setup:**

ScrollView:
Anchored at 0 to parent view all around

ContentView: Anchored at 0 to Scroll View all around. Height and width bound to Parent View.

UIViews: Anchored at 0 to ContentView all around.

---

Any ideas what I can change to fix this issue?

Side note: I won't be against removing the ContentView, but couldn't get it working either way.

Comment: The content view should not have an equal height constraint to its parent view...

Comment: @AndréSlotta It doesn't make sense to me, but thats what a lot of tutorial do for Auto layout in scrollview. What do I equal its height to? I tried constant heights but that didn't work

Comment: The content view does not get any kind of explicit height constraint. Instead you have to make sure that all the views within your content view have valid constraints from the very top of your content view to the very bottom so that it can calculate its own size.

Comment: @AndréSlotta Thank you for your assistance. The views inside the content view are xibs, the only constraint I couldn't get is between the last view element(eg uibutton) of the xib(s) and the bottom of the actual xib. Doesn't seem to allow me, makes the whole view weird. But will try focus on that, see if that will resolve anything

Comment: @AndréSlotta Thank you so much - I got it working. The 'complete' height constraint in the xib was the missing piece.

Comment: For someone else who might have same same height issue. The last view element that needs to be anchored to the bottom of the xib needs to have a lowered priority (250 for example). That lets the height change correctly

Answer (score 4):

I've setup the things as you set.

```
Scrollview-> Content view-> subview1
                           |-> subview2
                              |-> btn
                              |-> lbl
```

I've given following constraints...

- For the **scrollview**, I've given top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to its superview.
- For **content view (inside scrollview)**, I've given top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to its scrollview.
- For **subview1 (inside content view)**, I have given top, leading, trailing and height constraints to content view.
- For **subview2 (inside content view and below subview1)**, I have given top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to content view.
- For **label (inside subview2)**, I have given top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to subview2.
- For **button (inside subview2)**, I've given trailing and top constraints to subview2.

See the pic.

[image]

Final output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mahendra GP. Your solution would work I believe. But I was able to figure it out from what AndréSlotta mentioned on the comments.

Comment: @cfl this person took the time to give you a detailed answer. Whether you think you figured it out or not this is the first correct answer with a lot of detail so it should be marked correctly. Otherwise people such as the person that answered will not take the time to start Xcode and build an answer for you only to say I figured it out. If that was the case you should have provided an answer.

Comment: @agibson007, Thanks for appreciating my effort.

Comment: @agibson007 I wasn't sure what to do though cause Andre' gave me the answers I needed before I saw this reply, I couldn't mark him as correct, cause it was just comments. Mahendra GP I do appreciate your efforts and your answer is of value, but wouldn't have solved everything I was struggling with, it was the height constraint that I was missing. It would solve the issue if the sub views where shown at the same time, in my case they are interchangeable.

Comment: @cfl No problem. I'm very happy that I could help you. I'm here to help people like you. So I don't mind if you don't mark this answer, it may be useful to other people as well.